# how to passng data into foreach where id is the header from foreach using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have this databases, that i want to make separate group that looks like this...
[image]
every each title (black bird, falcon, etc) is foreach from `id`/`program`, and every sub title (producer, associate producer, creative, production assistant) are foreach where id are title (black bird, etc), and every name bellow sub title are foreach where id are sub title (producer). So for easy way are like this.[image]

and here is my database.
[image]

so i wreck my head and think about how to foreach every item and here are i using this function on my controller.

**controller**

```
 public function listReportCrew(){
    $id = DB::select('select distinct show_name from view_mastercrewprogram');

        $getpost = array();                           
        foreach($id as $program){
            $positions = array(DB::select("select distinct crewprogramposition_name
                                        from view_mastercrewprogram where show_name = '". $program->show_name ."'"));
            array_push($getpost, $positions);
        }

        $getemployee = arreay();
        foreach($getpost as $postname){
            $employee = array(DB::select("select employee_nik, employee_nama 
                                        from view_mastercrewprogram where crewprogramposition_name =
                                        '". $postname->crewprogramposition_name. "'"));
            array_push($getemployee, $employee);
        }
    // $reportviewall = ReportViewAll::all();
    return view('CrewProgram.ListReportCrew.index', compact('id', 'getpost', 'getemployee'));
}
```

So basically i tried to get every item and put it into array, and do something like that twice fore my postitions and my employee, and the other part is here i put some foreach on my blade that can make it looping over and over like this

**index blade php**

```
@foreach($id as $program)
   <div class=" mt-5 ml-2 mr-3">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="text-center">
         <h4>{{$program->show_name}}</h4>
       </div>
     </div>
   <div class="row">
       @foreach($getpost as $positions)
         <div class="col">
           <div>
              <div>{{$positions->crewprogramposition_name}}</div>

                 @foreach($getemployee as $employee)
                  <p>{{$employee->employee_name}}</p>
                 @endforeach

             </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
     </div>
   </div>
 @endforeach
```

Basically i just want to foreach an title , foreach a subtitle and then foreach every employe name, just multiple foreach for every data, how can i solve that?? i tried that and didn't works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wait for another answer using laravel solutions, because i just solve it using php,
i mean my solutions like brute forcing this problems, where i just selecting the data and making it like crystall reports.

**blade.php**

```
<?php
 echo '<div class="container  card shadow m-3">
 <div class="card-body m-2 p-2">
  <div class=" mt-5 ml-2 mr-3">
 <div class="row">';

    foreach($id as $program){
            echo '<div><hr><h1>'.$program->show_name.'</h1><div><hr>';

    $positions = DB::select("select distinct crewprogramposition_name from view_mastercrewprogram where show_name = '".$program->show_name."'");

    foreach($positions as $post){
       echo '<br><div>'.$post->crewprogramposition_name.'<div>';

       $employee = DB::select("select employee_nama
        from view_mastercrewprogram where crewprogramposition_name = '"  .$post->crewprogramposition_name."' AND show_name = '".$program->show_name."'");

        foreach($employee as $emp){
          echo '<div>'. $emp->employee_nama.'<div>';
        }
    }
}

 echo '</div></div></div></div>';
?>
```

**controller**

```
public function listReportCrew(){
    $id = DB::select('select distinct show_name from view_mastercrewprogram');
    return view('CrewProgram.ListReportCrew.index', compact('id'));
}
```

for controller, i just using a little line of code to get an id (actually it can be using in view too but i just want to make it in laravel because to empower the framework that i used). So hope for another persons will answer me using laravel solutions (making controller for getting the data)